Form linked Spreadsheet Server Error with Too many Columns from Form Questions
I have google forms that are linked to a spreadsheet. Every night, the questions on the forms have been resetting and creating new ones. Unfortunately, I have run into a server error on the spreadsheet because it reached the limit on the number of columns. Each form question including the deleted ones are linked to a column. Is there any way I can salvage this form data? The data with too many columns is linked to the form so even if I link the forms to a new spreadsheet, it has the same server error issue.
Any idea how I get myself out of this mess? Thank you so much!

Could you please explain what you mean by "how I get myself out of this mess"?

Every night, the questions on the forms have been resetting and creating new ones. 1) Would you please explain the reason why you are resetting and changing the question each night. 2) Since the "old" spreadsheet doesn't match the "new" form, why not add create a new linked spreadsheet every night?

Delete some old questions, use Google Apps Script or use the Google Forms API.

Delete and recreate the linked Sheet
When a Form is linked to a Sheet, columns are created in the Sheet for all current questions and no columns are created for any deleted questions. As “new” questions are added, additional columns are added to the linked Sheet; but if questions are deleted, those “old” columns are retained.
The solution is to open the Form and delete the existing link, and then create a new link.
In most cases, the new link can be created to the same spreadsheet (a new Sheet will be created). But if the existing spreadsheet has/will/may exceed data limits, linking to a new spreadsheet would be advisable.
Footnote
ALL response data is retained in the Form and a script can be used to generate responses data.
